# SQL over Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

This is the code to run simple SQL queries over Spark Streaming.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{Seconds, StreamingContext}
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration

object StreamingSQL {

  case class Persons(name: String, age: Int)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("HdfsWordCount")
    val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
    // Create the context
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

    val lines = ssc.textFileStream("C:/Users/pravesh.jain/Desktop/people/")
    lines.foreachRDD(rdd=>rdd.foreach(println))

    val sqc = new SQLContext(sc);
    import sqc.createSchemaRDD

    // Create the FileInputDStream on the directory and use the
    // stream to count words in new files created

    lines.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
      rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(p => Persons(p(0), p(1).trim.toInt)).registerAsTable("data")
      val teenagers = sqc.sql("SELECT name FROM data WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")
      teenagers.foreach(println)
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

As you can see, to run SQL over streaming, the query has to be made inside the foreachRDD method.
I want to run SQL join over data received from two different streams. Is there any way that can be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, I would like to sum up the workaround we arrived on after the discussion in the answer by **Spiro**. His suggestion to first create an empty table and then inserting RDDs into it was bang on. The only problem is that **Spark doesn't allow to insert into tables yet**. Here is what can be done:

First, create an RDD that has the same schema as the one you're expecting from your stream:

```scala
import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
val d1=sc.parallelize(Array(("a",10),("b",3))).map(e=>Rec(e._1,e._2))
```

Then save it as a **Parquet File**

```scala
d1.saveAsParquetFile("/home/p1.parquet")
```

Now, load the parquet file and register it as table using the **registerAsTable()** method.

```scala
val parquetFile = sqlContext.parquetFile("/home/p1.parquet")
parquetFile.registerAsTable("data")
```

Now, when you receive your stream, just apply a **foreachRDD()** on your stream and keep inserting the individual RDDs in the table created above using the **insertInto()** method

```scala
dStream.foreachRDD(rdd=>{
rdd.insertInto("data")
})
```

This insertInto() works fine and allows the data to be collected into a table. Now you can do the same for any number of streams and then run your queries.

Answer (score 5):

The way you've written your code, you end up producing a sequence of little SchemaRDDs each time you run a SQL query. The trick is to save each of these to either an accumulation RDD or an accumulation table.

**First**, the table approach, using `insertInto`:

For each of your streams, first create an emty RDD that you register as a table, obtaining an empty table. For your example, let's say you call it "allTeenagers".

Then, for each of your queries, use SchemaRDD's `insertInto` method to add the result to that table:

```
teenagers.insertInto("allTeenagers")
```

If you do this with both your streams, creating two separate accumulation tables, you can then join them using a plain old SQL query.

(Note: I haven't actually been able to get his to work, and a little searching makes me doubt that anybody else has, but I'm pretty sure I've understood the design intent of `insertInto`, so I think this solution is worth recording.)

**Second**, the `unionAll` approach (there's also a `union` method but that makes it trickier to get the types right):

This involves creating an initial RDD -- again let's call it `allTeenagers`.

```
// create initial SchemaRDD even if it's empty, so the types work out right
var allTeenagers = sqc.sql("SELECT ...")
```

Then, each time:

```
val teenagers = sqc.sql("SELECT ...")
allTeenagers = allTeenagers.unionAll(teenagers)
```

Perhaps needless to say that you need the columns to match up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried something like
`var p1 = Person("Hari",22);    val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(p1));    rdd1.registerAsTable("data");    var p2 = Person("sagar", 22);    var rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array(p2));    rdd2.insertInto("data");`
and getting the error "java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: No plan for InsertIntoTable Map(), false"

Seems I'm using the insertInto() the wrong way?

Comment: @Pravesh: I have the same problem. I'm pretty sure it's supposed to work but some searching makes me wonder if anybody uses it. I'm curious what replies you get to the question you posted on the Spark list. I updated my answer with a second solution that I'm pretty sure will work based on `unionAll`, which I'm surprised nobody there has suggested yet. A simple example of the latter works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable suggestions. Keep me updated if you find something new. Will do the same.

Comment: There was a reply from the Spark mailing list confessing that insertInto is not supported into tables yet. They asked me to try and use parquetFile (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files) but that's also giving he same error. 
I guess the last option is to try and use hive tables.

Comment: @Pravesh: have you already ruled out the second solution in my answer, (unionAll) for some reason?

Comment: That would only be useful if I want to collect data from different stream into a single schemaRDD. That won't help me run join queries such as `SELECT people.name, names.age FROM people INNER JOIN names ON people.age=names.age` where people and names and two different tables.

Comment: @Pravesh: I was not proposing that you collect data from different streams into a single RDD, but rather that you collect the RDD fragments fed to you by `foreachRDD` from EACH stream into an accumulator table/RDD, resulting in two tables or two RDDs that you could then join (each containing all the data from the corresponding  stream so far)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry I couldn't reply early.
Using rdd.union method works fine. Except that you have to wait for the stream to end to do the operations, which kind of beats the point of streaming.

I tried something else also : the concept of Parquet files. You save any initial RDD into a parquet file then load it back and register it as table. Inserting into this table works as expected and seems a little better. So using this right now. Although, SparkSQL seems very naive now (for ex. insertInto not working). When it gets better in the next few releases, it would be extremely useful.