# How to optimize huge spark dataframe SQL query to compare values from spark streaming RDDs?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

I am creating a demo that uses spark SQL (data frames) and spark streaming. I am no spark expert my any means so I need some help!

I load about ~1million objects from a DB to spark Dataframe and I do SQL queries to match some fields with that and the live data from spark streaming.

For example,

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE Person.name='stream.name' AND Person.age='stream.age' AND ... etc
```

stream.xxx is a java string which I extract from spark streaming RDD into a string.

Now, the problem is that with a dataframe of 1 million rows and several columns, the SQL query above can take some time to execute even if the DF is persisted in memory. I had an idea where I would break up the Person table into zip code regions (each dataframe contains Person from 1 region) and process each spark stream RDD on each dataframe. This would reduce query times and makes things faster.

I am not sure how I would do the partition though. Heres some sample code.

```
// Setup Spark Stream with receiver
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> transaction = jssc.receiverStream(new TransactionStreamReceiver(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK()));

DataFrame person1 = //load logic ommitted
DataFrame person2 = //load logic ommitted
DataFrame person3 = //load logic ommitted

// Break up Person table for faster processing
transaction.foreachRDD(new TransactionProcessingFunction(person1, sqlContext, window,1));

transaction.foreachRDD(new TransactionProcessingFunction(person2, sqlContext, window,2));

transaction.foreachRDD(new TransactionProcessingFunction(person3, sqlContext, window,2));
```

I assumed that each worker node will process a foreachRDD method, but this is not the case. Is there any way I can assign each worker to run each foreachRDD in parallel?

EDIT: The TransactionProcessingFunction class is essentially just a forloop that loops through the stream data and does the query above and show some results.

Comment: Do you need all the columns from the output?

Comment: I need about 6 columns, I used * because I didn't want to type it all out :P

Comment: If you don't need all the columns, best to filter early by being specific.

Comment: But you would still have 1 million rows, which is still alot of comparison. Im looking for a way to parallelize parts of the Persons table, spark should be able to do this, I just don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to get the necromancer silver medal directing you [to this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25484879/sql-over-spark-streaming) to see how to load a SQL table inside the stream. Once you create a table object, you could `repartition()` the rdd or simply let the Spark Environmnet do its job.